# How to read characters and integers separately

Tags: java, regex, string, java.util.scanner

I have to read the following symbols with Scanner and process them separately.

The input is:

```
@@@xx@*
1 -1 -1 4
```

The first line is the life and food of a game animal, the second row are her moves the `-` to the left, `+` to the right

I start with something, but not enough:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\s*");
while (!sc.hasNext("z")) {
    char ch = sc.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.print("[" + ch + "] "); // to check what is happening
}
```

How to read the second row of integers with `-` and `+` and then operate with them?

Comment: You should use a serialization library for this task

Comment: You get input at one time? Or firstly get first line and then second one?

Comment: Simply you can do like  `while (s.hasNext()) {System.out.println(s.nextInt());}`

Comment: The first line first, then  the second one

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scanner 's built-in methods like `nextInt()` and `next()` also look for something like `hasNextInt()` it can be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

You can use various scanner class functions to do that. Input is:
1 -1 -1 4

Create two arrays to store characters '-' and '+' and one to store integers

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(sc.hasNext()){
   if(sc.hasNextInt()){
         intArray = sc.nextInt();
   }
   else charArray = sc.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java Scanner class has a whole bunch of methods for grabbing and parsing the next part of a string, e.g. `next()`, `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, etc.

The code looks like this:

```
String input = "1 -1 -1 4";
Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
int i1 = s.nextInt();
int i2 = s.nextInt();
int i3 = s.nextInt();
int i4 = s.nextInt();
```

Will read all four values

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the input character to integer if it parses then you can continue your code if it throws number format exception then you should know input character is not a number.

```
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\s*");

    while (!sc.hasNext("z")) {
        char ch = sc.next().charAt(0);
        try {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ch));
            switch (a){
                case 1:
                    // your condition
                case -1:
                    // your condition
                case -4:
                    //condition
                default:
                    // your condition
            }
        }catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            System.out.printf("input character is not number");
        }
        System.out.print("[" + ch + "] ");// to chack what is happening
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read whole line instead read by characters. Then split line into String array which will be contains chars of lines and operate with array. Here the solution of your case `line.replaceAll("(-*[\\W\\d\\w])(\\s*)", "$1 ")`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (!sc.hasNext("z")) {
  String line = sc.nextLine();
  String[] split = line.replaceAll("(-*[\\W\\d\\w])(\\s*)", "$1 ").trim().split(" ");
  Arrays.asList(split).forEach(ch -> System.out.print(ch + " "));
}
}
```

Output:

```
@@@xx@*
@ @ @ x x @ * 

1 -1 -1 4 
1 -1 -1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

as most of the people is saying you can use scanner.nextInt() and about watching if you have to go the left or to the right you have the method Math.signum() which tells you were to go and then you can take the Math.abs() to get the value as an absolute number.